# Java utility unable to find and read its properties file

Tags: classpath, classloader, properties-file

I have to execute a java utility  (UTL.jar) through a shell script (mainUTL.sh). It utilizes a properties file (SetupUTL.properties).

The location of the files is as following -
    /a/b/mainUTL.sh
    /a/b/UTL.jar
    /a/b/SetupUTL.properties

I have setup my CLASSPATH as following in the mainUTL.sh -

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/a/b/SetupUTL.properties:/a/b/UTL.jar
```

I am executing the script from command prompt (Login shell is csh) as following -

```
sh mainUTL.sh <$ARG1> &
```

and the script mainUTL.sh has the following java execution command -

```
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -d64 UTL.jar <$ARG1>
```

Now when I am executing the shell script from location /a/b/ as  following

```
/a/b$: sh mainUTL.sh <$ARG1> &
```

The utility is executing fine.
But when I am executing the shell script from any other location say /a/ as  following

```
/a$: sh mainUTL.sh <$ARG1> &
```

The utility is unable to find its properties file. The utility has following piece of code -

```
  private boolean initPropertiesAndLog()
  {
    String str1 = null;
    String str2 = null;

    InputStream localInputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("SetupUTL.properties");
    if (localInputStream == null) {
      System.out.println("Unable to read SetupUTL.properties.properties file.");
      return false;
    }
```

I am not at all aware of Java codes, so please tell me what wrong I am doing as to not able to execute the utility fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`

Try this

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_prop_file")
```

if fails, try to add a "/":

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/your_prop_file")
```